# Dependency Injection Symfony 2 simple code returning error

Tags: symfony

I was under the impression I could get the request object like in the code below. Something to do with Dependency Injection.

This below is activated as a service and everything seems to be setup correctly except for the first argument which gives this error:

ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to....

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\BundleName\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class RequestListener
{

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {

        $request = $event->getRequest();

        // etc....
```

I'm guessing the above is not how you do it?

Comment: We need the whole exception

Comment: I think I've worked it out by passing '@service_container' in as an argument (services.yml). I've heard that's not a good method though?

Comment: it means that whatever you were passing before it wasn't a `GetResponseEvent` object

Comment: I wasn't passing in anything before. So is  '@service_container'  a bad method, or is that ok to use?

Comment: can you edit your question with your service's parameters? It's either defined in services.yml or services.xml or config.yml

Comment: I'm passing in '@service_container', but I understand that passing in the whole container is not a good method. What is the alternative. There are no error messages now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare an event listener on the kernel request, you should declare it that way (notice the tags parameters):

```
services:
    acme.demobundle.listener.request:
        class: Acme\Bundle\BundleName\EventListener\RequestListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Otherwise, if you want to create just a service, you should declare it that way

```
services:
    acme.demobundle.demo.service:
        class: Acme\Bundle\BundleName\Service\DemoService
        arguments: [@service_container]
```

For a service or a listener, I'd advise injecting only the services that are needed.

It's good to know that a service will be initialized on the first call.

A service, a listener and a twig extension can be accessed through the container.

```
$this->container->get('your.listener.name')
$this->container->get('your.service.name')
$this->container->get('your.extension.name')
```

Comment: Thanks. So, to do "I'd advise injecting only the services that are needed" how do I do that? What would I use instead of this line: arguments: [@service_container] to inject just the required part, something like arguments: [listener_name]

Comment: If you want to inject the request, you should be able to do `arguments: [@request]`. Request is a service so you can access through the container. You don't have to put anything there if you don't need it. You can remove the service_container if you don't need it.

Comment: Ok, great. I get it. Also, in that listener class, I want to set a cookie, and I'm using $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie(etc...)) but how do I get access to the $response object? My problem is getting access to everything I need to.

Comment: So the event `kernel.request` is not aware of the response. The response object is created once your action was processed entirely. Instead you should be using the [kernel.response event](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html#kernel-response-event) which get triggered after the controller action returns a Response.